# Twilio 10DLC ISV implementation

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am implementing a 10DLC verification for my company, we have the primary profile registered as ISV type, and we gonna follow this workflow :

https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/compliance/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#1-a2p-10dlc-overview
[image]

but I still have so many questions, I need some answers from a Twilio expert before starting the real work.

. I need to create a Secondary customer profile for our customers, I am following this doc ISV Standard Registration :
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/compliance/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#12-create-an-empty-secondary-customer-profile-bundle

but our customers are individuals who don't have any international Tax ID, can I use just our EIN number on every new customer profile? on this step :
https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/compliance/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv-api#14-create-end-user-of-type-authorized_representative_1

Thank you for reading here, for any supplementary questions you can ask me in the comment,

I am waiting for your help, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The identification requirements for a successful A2P 10DLC registration are as follows:

> Please note that if you are a U.S. business with an EIN, a Canadian
> business with a Canadian Business Number, or are headquartered in any
> country outside of the U.S., Canada, EU, UK, or Australia you must
> register as a Standard Brand for A2P 10DLC purposes. The other option,
> a Sole Proprietor Brand, is available only for U.S. or Canadian
> customers who do not have an EIN or Canadian Business Number.

The same is true for subaccounts and Secondary Profiles. A social social security number can be used in place of an EIN. Twilio previously allowed DUNS numbers in place of EIN but that is no longer the case. [EIN registration](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/apply-for-an-employer-identification-number-ein-online) can be done online at the [irs.gov](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/apply-for-an-employer-identification-number-ein-online) website.

Also, check the [ISV Architecture Type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/compliance/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#identify-your-isv-type) to make sure you are using the best fitting entity type.

[ISV Architecture Type 1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/compliance/a2p-10dlc/onboarding-isv#isv-architecture-1) is what Twilio recommends:

> We would recommend this as the preferred architecture for A2P 10DLC
> Brand and Campaign registration. In this architecture, the messaging
> traffic of each end customer is clearly separated from that of every
> other end customer. In a case where one of your customers is a bad
> actor and sends non-compliant messages, Twilio could decide to suspend
> their account. Having each subaccount mapped to an individual customer
> allows you to minimize impact when this happens because the
> noncompliant traffic is isolated. Moreover, separating your customers
> into subaccounts allows much easier analytics tracking of individual
> customers’ messaging activity.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, that's means we can use our EIN on every new secondary profile because we don't have currently any of their EINs or social security numbers, this will take time to ask them to provide this information

Comment: u didn't answer my question yet, is that mean we need to ask our Customers to provide us the EIN number of there business or we can just use ours ?